# Remove all tags of a tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text

Is there a way to remove all of the tags on a text widget in tkinter?

```
text.tag_config("NONE",font=Font(family="Arial",size=10))
text.add_tag("NONE","1.0","end")
```

does not work. If I make part of the text colored red and try to remove that tag, nothing happens. The only way I can clear the tag (as a user) is to delete the text that was tagged with red.

Comment: Any span of text can have any number of tags applied to it - so adding a new tag is not going to get rid of an old one.  You have to explicitly `.tag_remove()` or `.tag_delete()` the old tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove any single tag, use `tag_remove`, giving it the tag name. To remove from the entire document use the index "1.0" and "end"

```
text.tag_remove("the_tag", "1.0", "end")
```

To remove all tags, iterate over a list of all tags. You can get a list of all the tags with `tag_names()`. The list will include all of your custom tags along with the tag "sel" which is used to manage the selection.

```
for tag in text.tag_names():
    text.tag_remove(tag, "1.0", "end")
```