# How to remove Tags on tkinter.Text without losing the color. Also i want to being able to use the name of the tag again

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter with python and i'm trying to create a tag to define a section of text inside the Text widget. then I want to remove the tag, without the color of the text disappearing. I need to remove it so i can use the name of the tag again. Here is my code:

```
def update_win(coord, state):
    text_win.tag_add("color", f"{coord[1] + 1}.{coord[0]}", f"{coord[1] + 1}.{coord[0] + 1}")
    if state == 0:
        text_win.tag_configure("color", foreground="black")
    else:
        text_win.tag_configure("color", foreground="red")

    time.sleep(1)
    text_win.tag_remove("color", "1.0", "end")
```

This gets ran many times

The problem is when I remove the tag the color goes away. But if i don't remove it the tags they all get added up into one big tag and then the color controls them all at once.

Comment: Tags are the one and only way that you can apply color and other style changes to parts of a Text - if you remove the tag, you inherently remove the color.  If the problem is that you need to control the color of multiple pieces of text independently, then you need to give them distinct tags - add a numeric suffix to the tag name, perhaps.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644083/remove-all-tags-of-a-tkinter-text-widget

Comment: Some times I use mic colors for irc chat

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't recycle tag names like that. Use a tag name encoding the color information such as `color-#000000`.

This is an example.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

text.insert('end', 'abcd')

def set_color(start, end, color):
    tag_name = 'color-' + color
    text.tag_configure(tag_name, foreground=color)
    text.tag_add(tag_name, start, end)

set_color('1.1', '1.3', 'red')

root.mainloop()
```